# String type in header files

Tags: c++

I am working on a project and i have three header files each defining a seperate struct with some function for accessing the variables this is an example of the student struct:

```
#include<string.h>
//using namespace std;
struct student
{
    int studentId;
    string fname;
    string lname;
};
void SetId(student * stu,int id)
{
    stu->studentId=id;
}
void SetFirstName(student * stu,string name)
{
    stu->fname=name;    
}
void SetLastName(student * stu,string name)
{
    stu->lname=name;
}
int GetId(student * stu)
{
    return stu->studentId;
}
string GetFirstName(student * stu)
{
    return stu->fname;
}
string GetLastName(student * stu)
{
    return stu->lname;
}
```

when i compile this file i get two errors:
1.  [Error] unknown type name 'string' 
2. [Error] unknown type name 'student'

Comment: `#include<string.h>` includes a header of the C library that should be included as `<cstring>` in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `string` with `std::string`.

You've done the good thing and got rid of the intrusive `using namespace std;`.

Finally, why not make the "global functions" members of the `student` class itself? Then you wouldn't need that `student*` pointer.  C++ ain't C you know.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using C++, you should avoid to include `.h` header. There's the `<string>` header in C++ to manipulate string, so use it.

Then, you have commented the `using namespace std` which is a good practice. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1452738/7943474) why. But now you need to specify which namespace string objects belong to, so it's necessary to explicity write `std::string` istead of `string`.

Finally, I quote @Bathsheba answer. You should create a class student.